# Continuation with Tasks (instead of delegates)

Tags: c#, task, async-await, continuations

I have a class where each method execute asynchronously, i.e. return a Task, but where each method should nevertheless wait for the completion of the preceding call.

Continuation, right?

Except that a task continuation takes a delegate (Action) in parameter, not another task.

I've tried different things and the best I could do to make it work is the following (to me quite complex) code:

```
    private Task QueueTask(Func<Task> futureTask)
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        _lastTask.ContinueWith(async t =>
        {
            try
            {
                await futureTask();

                completionSource.SetResult(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                completionSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        _lastTask = completionSource.Task;

        return _lastTask;
    }
```

Here _lastTask is a private member of my class.  Since all calls are coming from the UI thread, I just keep the last task and put continuation on it.

As I said I find this code quite convoluted.  Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear that what you've got actually does what you want it to anyway. What do your `Func<Task>` methods do? If they're creating their own tasks, are they also starting them? If you could provide a short but *complete* example, it would really help.

Comment: Also, have you seen the overloads for `ContinueWith` that accept a `Func<Task, Task<TResult>>`? It seems like the problem is more that you're ignoring the existing task part, than the return value part...

Answer (score 2):

To me, it seems like you're asking the wrong question. A queue of tasks like this is an unusual requirement. We don't know anything about the actual problem you're trying to solve, so we can't suggest better approaches.

`ContinueWith` is intended for dynamic parallel processing, so it doesn't *quite* fit in with `async` code. However, you can use `ContinueWith` paired with `Unwrap` to sort-of emulate the behavior of `await` (if you ignore how `await` interacts with the current context).

So you can simplify your queue of tasks solution as such:

```
private Task QueueTask(Func<Task> futureTask)
{
    _lastTask = _lastTask.ContinueWith(t => futureTask()).Unwrap();
    return _lastTask;
}
```

However, there are probably better solutions. If the purpose of the queue is to provide exclusive access, a `SemaphoreSlim` would be more natural. If you actually do need a queue for some reason, consider using a Dataflow mesh.